# Resize all cards in a row if one is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular

I have four cards that are visible on top of the page. The height of the card changes according to the text inside it. The cards resize when the window is resized as well. I want to make sure that all the cards in a row have the same height.

Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xv3syn

What I'm trying to do is to get the max-height among the cards, and set the same height for other cards. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you make an array of heights and use [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to determine the max height and use it in all cards?

Comment: That will just replace the if else part. I'm already setting the max height to other cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in you column item

```
.col-md-6{
  display:grid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with CSS property `display: flex;`.

Comment: Without an example, this is just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

i just change column size now you can see all have same size, you can get this thing by assign appropriate size to each column 
[image]

Comment: Try and avoid posting screenshots of code/examples. It's almost always better to post a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).